# Find min,max, inf, sup (if they exist) of the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}+\sin \frac{n \pi}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

We've been given the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}+\sin \frac{n \pi}{2}$.

I have to find the min, max, inf and sup (if they exist), and also find the points of accumulation.

I have no idea how to do that because I only worked with simple sequences that are monotone increasing or decreasing, and this one isn't so easy.

Comment: What's the difference between $\max$ and $\sup$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathrm{{d\over dx}{x^{0.5}\over(1+x)}=-{x^{0.5}\over(1+x)^2}+{0.5\over x^{0.5}(1+x)}={0.5(1-x)\over x^{0.5}(1+x)^2}<0\;\forall\;x>1}$$
So $\mathrm{\sqrt{n}\over n+1}$ is strictly decreasing.$\quad\cdots(1)$

Also
$$\mathrm{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{n}\over n+1}=0}\quad\cdots(2)$$
$\mathrm{\sin\left({k\pi\over2}\right)=0,1,0,-1}$ at $\mathrm{k=4n,4n+1,4n+2,4n+3}$ respectively.$\quad\cdots(3)$

Using $(1),(2),(3)$ we see 
$$
\mathrm{\sup_{n\ge0}x_{4n}={2\over5}},\quad\mathrm{\sup_{n\ge0}x_{4n+2}={\sqrt{2}\over3}},\quad 
\mathrm{\sup_{n\ge0}x_{4n+1}=1},\quad\mathrm{\sup_{n\ge0}x_{4n+3}=-1}\\
\mathrm{\inf_{n\ge0}x_{4n}=0},\quad\mathrm{\inf_{n\ge0}x_{4n+2}=0},\quad
\mathrm{\inf_{n\ge0}x_{4n+1}={1\over2}},\quad\mathrm{\inf_{n\ge0}x_{4n+3}=-{\sqrt{3}\over4}-1}
$$ 
So $$\mathrm{\sup_{n\ge0}x_n=1,\quad\inf_{n\ge0}x_n=-{\sqrt{3}\over4}-1}$$
and using $(2),(3)$ the accumulation points are $0,\pm1$.

Comment: So, $(-1)^n$ doesn't effect anything, and what about min and max? It was very helpfull, I now understand a lot.

Comment: @Jack's wasted life I did it in hurry, your answer seems OK, I will delete my answer. Thanks! (+1)

Comment: @zermelovac For an infinite bounded set of reals A, max A=sup A,inf A=min A.Generally for finite sets we use max,min instead of sup,inf. What's your definition of max,min?